# Saving a JSON file to internal storage - Android

Tags: java, android, json, debugging

I've been trying to save a JSON (currently, it's simply a generic file) to my device's internal storage. I've looked at tons of examples that look exactly like what I've written, but I can never find the file on my device.

**Code to save file**

```
public void saveJSONStringToFile(String json) {
  FileOutputStream outfile = null;
  String filename = "json_test.json";

  try {
    outfile = openFileOutput(filename, this.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outfile.write(json.getBytes());
    outfile.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I know that it's not working because I've also implemented code to retrieve that file and the app just hangs when I try that, implying that it's looking for something that isn't there.

Comment: Please check the persmission in the manifest

Comment: obviously because other apps(like file manager) cannot see files from your app on non rooted devices

Comment: @DanyPoplawec What permission, exactly, should I be looking for?

Comment: @Selvin I wouldn't call that obvious. I assumed you could see them. But I've also used Android's built-in file explorer in the Storage menu and still wasn't able to see it.

Comment: it is obvious: ***MODE_PRIVATE - File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).*** ... also *Android's built-in file explorer* is still different app

Comment: Right. And by apps, I assumed it just meant android apps. I don't get the hostility or downvotes.

Edit: That clearly wasn't obvious to me. Look, I'm new to Android development and nothing I looked at specified that.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: And if you are on device API > 6 you should ask for permission at runtime

Comment: Does using external storage work if I don't have an SD card or if my phone isn't plugged into my computer? My understanding was that it wouldn't.

Comment: It will, External storage is basically the 'publicly visible' files, and internal storage is private to your app (so not visible to the user or other apps). You can find more information and a guide [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage).

Comment: Thanks, this worked correctly!